# Android emulator display size

Tags: android, size, emulation, resolution

I am developing an app to run on android. I have an emulator with the pixel resolution of an 10.1 inch tablet display, but emulator keeps running my app on a much smaller area on this large screen. Does anybody know how to configure an emulator properly using AVD? By the way im using IntelliJ as ide not an eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have to make an application for galaxy tab 10.1 inch then you have to do following :

- Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager
- Click on Available packages
- Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung
  Electronics add-ons.
- Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator. Under Target you
  will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select it.

Comment: else you can create new avd using custom resolution 1280X800 and then check your app :)

Comment: you can specify resolution and create a new avd from android avd manager